# Align row items in specific position inside a column widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Having difficulties in positioning row items inside the column widget in a specific marginal position like this image:

[image]

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        values('Date', ': ${DateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a').format(DateTime.parse(date))}', false),
        values('Description', ': $description', false),
      ],
    ),
  ),



Widget values(String title, String value, bool isAmount) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Text(
          value,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: isAmount ? Color(0xFF34B3C1) : Colors.black87,
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Expanded** and **flex** to achieve this,

```
  Widget values(String title, String value, bool isAmount) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Expanded(
          flex: 7,
          child: Text(
            value,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: isAmount ? Color(0xFF34B3C1) : Colors.black87,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can also try [FractionallySizedBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEsY654EGZ0)

Answer (score 1):

It could also work by putting **Text('Date')**, **Text(':')** and **Text('Description')**, **Text(':')** inside **children[]** and set Align to spaceBetween. 
For the values of Date and Description you put them also inside a Row() which is build inside first Row().

Both of the Text Widgets **Date** and **:**, **Description** and **:** can be placed inside Container()

```
 child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0, left: 12.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    border: new Border(
                      right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26)
                    )
                  ),
                  child: Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                  child: Text(
                    document['name'],
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ), 
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('0'),
                  Text('/'),
                  Text(document['value'].toString())
                ],)
            )          
          ]
        ),
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you make it more understandable with a sample code? This might help others as well.